# Make pixel matrix with TextView

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

my main idea is to create a pixel matrix and access each cell in my code to change the color of it 
I get the idea to use Textview from  [PixelArtist](https://github.com/RodrigoDavy/PixelArtist)

I want to show my matrix(35*10) in part of the screen (for example 40% of screen size)& app run only in landscape mode .my problem is application only shows one row.
 [image from simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi94e.png)

mainactivity.xml code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_mid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_low"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.60" />



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pic_frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline_low">

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />

        <include layout="@layout/paper_line" />



    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

my paperline.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />

    <TextView style="@style/Pixel" />




</LinearLayout>
```

and pixel style

```
    <style name="Pixel">
        <item name="android:layout_width">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">1dp</item>
               <item name="background">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `my paperline.xml` height is set to `match_parent` change that to `wrap_content`

also if youre not planning on putting any text in them, then you can probably just use `View` instead of `TextView`

---

Also if you don't mind each box changing size, and you want to squish the all into whatever view than you can change the following:

Make your pixel look like:

```
    <style name="Pixel">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">1dp</item>
        <item name="background">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

And make the top of `my paperline.xml` look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp">
```

By setting width or height of a view inside a `LinearLayout` to `0dp` and providing a weight, the view will dynamically calculate the width/height based on the weight. If all weight are the same then it will all be evenly distributed.

Comment: thanks.now show only 6 row instant of my 10-row .i want always show my complete matrix on any landscape size

Comment: @ali try the changes i just suggested in my updated answer